# errors on eclipse startup (WebDev + JBoss Tools + Tomcat)

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jsf-2

i'm running into following errors everytime i start eclipse. If i move my project to a new workspace, everything works fine for the duration of one session - as soon as i open eclipse for the next time, the same thing is popping up again.

I tried various suggestions i found in other posts (closing/reopening project, validation, cleaning,etc.) without success. [Here](http://eckquarters.com/eclipse_error_log.txt) is my stacktrace from the last session (its too long to post it directly in here:))

The main symptom is that Tomcat doesnt start - it is stuck at 7%.
Thank you guys in advance, your help is highly appreciated!! If you need anything else, just leave me a comment and i i'll post it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Eclipse environment is seriously messed up. Perhaps you installed plugins the wrong way or you used the wrong Eclipse or plugin version.

Trash everything. Delete the Eclipse program folder altogether. You can keep your workspace folder, but you should delete its `.metadata` folder. Now download a fresh copy of [Eclipse for Java EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) (note, with the EE!), extract it and then integrate Tomcat again the usual way by the *Servers* view. Note that you don't need any additional plugins for this step.

JBoss Tools should be installed via *Help > Install New Software*. You should specify the JBoss Tools update site matching the exact Eclipse version. Currently it's Indigo SR2, so you should specify http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/indigo/SR2/ as URL.

Comment: You're welcome. Be careful when installing future plugins. Eclipse is at its own stable, but it are the poor/wrong plugins which can seriously messup things.